Security with microservices, Spring boot
hope you are doing well. I am learning about microservices using Spring Boot, and currently, I'm investigating security in microservices with JWT tokens.
I have an authorization service (which handles user creation, login, sign-up, etc.), a main service (which contains some business logic), and an API gateway. As I understand, we should use the API gateway to check if the token exists and if it is valid.
However, I have some questions:
How can I get the authenticated user in the main service? In a monolithic application, I would save it in the SecurityContextHolder in a "one-per-request" filter.
What if there is an endpoint in the main service that needs to be secured not only by a valid JWT (which I currently check in the API gateway) but also by the roles that the authenticated user has?
What is the best practice to implement this? Should I add a "one-per-request" filter to the main service (and, in the future, to all other services) to call the authorization service, check the JWT, and get user information from it? Is it a good idea to make a call to the authorization service for every request?
Additionally, for role-based security, should I also configure secured endpoints for each service?

Maby you can allow your service to return some kind of permissions Dto that you could cache then?

This is actually the hole purpose of JWT: you can generate a token that holds information about the user and information about his role and authorizations, this token is signed from the authorization service but other services does not need to call the authorization service or database to know the user information or the role of that user, they only need a shared secret they use to check the validity of the token and they know all the info inside the token is valid
so what you do is the following:
Token Generation:

When a user logs in, the authorization service generates a JWT. The
JWT holds user information (like username, roles, permissions).
The token is signed by the authorization service using a secret key.
The     signing ensures that the token can’t be tampered with.

No Need for Continuous Authorization Service Calls:

Once the token is issued, other services don’t need to query the
authorization service or the database to verify the user’s identity
or roles.
This is because the information about the user is inside the JWT, and
it’s signed by the authorization service.
The services can trust the token as long as the signature is valid,
and they share a secret key to verify the signature.

Validation of Token:

When a user makes a request to a service, they send their JWT.
The service checks the token’s signature using the shared secret key.
If the signature is valid, the service extracts the user’s information (including roles and authorizations) from the token.
This is why it doesn’t need to contact the authorization service again—it can trust the information inside the JWT.

Authorization:

Once the service verifies the JWT, it can check if the user has the necessary permissions based on the roles encoded in the token.
The service can then allow or deny access to the requested resource based on the role.

Conclusion:

JWT contains all the information you need, it is not like a session
ID, it is like a JSON object with all the info about the authenticated
user
JWT is validated with a signature


Currently, I have an endpoint in the authorization service that verifies the token, extracts claims from it, and returns a UserDto. I call this endpoint for each request. If I understand you correctly, you suggest moving the logic to extract user data from the JWT directly into my service, instead of calling the authorization endpoint, and handling the validation and data extraction within the service itself, right?

yes exactly, every service should be able to extract information from JWT itself without calling the authorization service
